# Binding in ContentControl Crash

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, contentcontrol

Can anyone tell me why this crashes my app? There seems to be some endless recursion by I can't figure out why. I get this exception

> Logical tree depth exceeded while
>   traversing the tree. This could
>   indicate a cycle in the tree

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding MyString}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

And this is all I have as Source

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyString = "Test";
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public string MyString { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're using MainWindow as the DataContext of the MainWindow's content. When you set `Content="{Binding}"` on the ContentControl this is setting the ContentControl's content to the MainWindow instance. This is a problem because the ContentControl is contained in the MainWindow's Content. Whenever a Content property receives a UIElement, it renders it as a UIElement, not through the DataTemplate as it would with an non-UI class. So your tree ends up being

```
MainWindow
 ContentControl
  MainWindow
   ContentControl
    ...
```

Using a separate data object for your DataContext instead of the window itself will give you the behavior you're looking for:

```
public partial class Window13 : Window
{
    public Window13()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyData data = new MyData();
        data.MyString = "Test";
        this.DataContext = data;
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: John, you're the man!! Works like a charm :) I can finally put this problem behind me and I also know the reason thanks to your very clear explanation! Thanks and merry christmas

Answer (score 3):

Although I totally agree with the accepted answer that you should not do this, sometimes you just don't have the choice. For instance, I'm using [Xceed PropertyGrid](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid) and the `DataContext` I have for each item of the grid is a `PropertyItem` which is a `UIElement` (containing the actual data in a `Value` member).

The workaround I found is to use a `ContentPresenter` instead of a `ContentControl`. The documentation is not clear about this but it seems that `UIElement` are templated instead of being used as-is.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding MyString}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the binding on the Content property of the ContentControl. What is this supposed to do anyway?

Comment: My understand of the ContentControl is that the DataContext within the DataTemplate is the Content of the ContentControl and not the DataContext. So if I remove it I don't get a DataContext within the DataTemplate to bind to at all. Any ideas?